# Need to solve unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, synaptic, aptitude

Since this morning I have been able to resolve unmet dependencies.

In the past always solved it by installing packages one by one, or installing the deb package, but in this case I can't do that.

I need to install `libvips-dev` in Xubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo  apt install libvips-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvips-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev
               Depends: libmagickwand-dev
               Depends: librsvg2-dev (>= 2.40.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also

```
sudo  aptitude install libvips-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 librsvg2-dev : Depends: librsvg2-2 (= 2.48.2-1) but 2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
                Depends: librsvg2-common (= 2.48.2-1) but 2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
```

---

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list` is the original,

In previous searches I saw many solutions and tried:

---

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt upgrade
```

---

```
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
sudo apt autoremove

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
apt --fix-broken install


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

.

---

```
sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
```

---

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
give me nothing
```

---

I can not install the library then try with apt or aptitude to install some of their dependencies:

`sudo apt install librsvg2-2=2.48.2-1` give me a big list of packages that will be removed

Then with aptitude, the same thing happens:

```
sudo aptitude install librsvg2-2=2.48.2-1
```

I must remove a lot of packages.

```
 Remove the following packages: 1 to 157
 Install the following packages: 157 - 164
 Leave the following dependencies unresolved:  161 to 187
```

If I do it, the system won't work anymore.

---

Also try: Synaptic->Edit->Fix Broken Packages

What I am doing wrong?

Is there any other package installer that can scan the repositories and recursively install all needed packages?

I suppose that apt and aptitude must to do it on its own.

The output of apt update is:

```
:sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Get:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease [57.7 kB]       
Hit:3 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [473 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1637 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [278 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1098 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [156 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [712 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [557 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [129 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66.6 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2464 B]
Fetched 5321 kB in 19s (287 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
userone@pc:~
:apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
linux-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-security 5.15.0.43.46~20.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.41.44~20.04.13]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-security 5.15.0.43.46~20.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.41.44~20.04.13]
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-security 5.15.0.43.46~20.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.41.44~20.04.13]
```

Comment: Please run `apt policy` on the troublesome packages and edit the output into your question. I feel it's unlikely that you have not modified your sources (ppas don't show up in sources.list)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at one of the problematic packages by checking those versions at http://packages.ubuntu.com:

- `librsvg2-2` v2.48.2-1 is in `focal`
- `librsvg2-2` v2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is in `focal-updates`

Aha. Look carefully at your sources.

According to your `apt update` output, you have the `focal` and `focal-security` pockets of the Ubuntu repositories enabled.

**But you're missing `focal-updates`**

Re-enable that pocket, run another `sudo apt update` because your sources changed, and then try your install again.

Comment: The sources.list is the  original, which line must to enable ?

Comment: There is not any PPA in the sources.list, also the sources.list.d folder was deleted, it only had a reference to visual studio code.

Comment: The question is marked as closed, but is not resolved, Previously to post I try all the command of "How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?" and still can not resolve the problem.

Comment: You must enable the `focal-updates` lines. Trying to "resolve dependencies" or muck about with PPAs when your own output clearly indicates a more important missing source seems a waste of your effort.